# Fira Sans + Beamer + Metropolis (with Dark Background): Bold Looks too Thin

Tags: beamer, fonts, luatex, overleaf

- I use the beautiful `metropolis` `beamer` theme with the `dark` `background` option.
- AFAIK, the theme uses [Fira Sans](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/firasans/) as the main font and I like it so far.
- The problem is that when I have a `\textbf` (bold) font then the `bold` letters look too similar to the `normalfont` letters.
- **Question:** Can I still use the same font but make the difference between normal and bold more visible for small font sizes? Ideally, I can use the solution on **Overleaf**.

---

```
% Compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[background = dark]{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
normaltext\textbf{textbf} 
\par
{\tiny normalfont\textbf{textbf}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try something like `\setsansfont[BoldFont={Fira Sans Black}]{Fira Sans Book}`. You can mix and match the usual styles (Thin, Light, Regular, Medium, SemiBold, Bold, ExtraBold, Black)

Comment: @Ingmar Thanks for the comment! I added the tag `overleaf` because it seems that your suggestion does not work on Overleaf (my bad for not mentioning that from the beginning).

Comment: @Ingmar See the answer (provided by samcarter), thx for your interest!

Comment: If you ever want to experiment with variable fonts, [this article](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/variable-fonts-in-real-life-how-to-use-and-love-them) discusses how they can be used to make fonts look equally bold whether against a light or a dark background.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- This is a **community answer** based on user `samcarter`'s [answer on a different platform](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2021) (it started as a chat).
- It is important to know that when you use **Overleaf**, that you can rely on a bunch of installed fonts (also teached to me by user `samcater`, see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F).

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[background = dark]{metropolis}

% The magic happens here
\setsansfont[ItalicFont={Fira Sans Light Italic},%
                 BoldFont={Fira Sans SemiBold},%
                 BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Italic}]%
                {Fira Sans Light}%
                                    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
normaltext\textbf{textbf} 
\par
{\tiny normalfont\textbf{textbf}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Improved Version

[image]

### Original Version

[image]

[image]